# How to convert ndarray to a pandas DataFrame |python|pandas|numpy|

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to convert my numpy array into a dataframe,

array:

```
array([[[9.447859e+06, 3.000000e+00, 1.350000e+01, 7.000000e+00]]

   [[9.447859e+06, 2.000000e+00, 1.350000e+01, 4.000000e+00]],

   [[9.447859e+06, 1.000000e+00, 1.350000e+01, 7.000000e+00]]])
```

expected output:

```
A            B            C            D
9.447859e+06 3.000000e+00 1.350000e+01 7.000000e+00
9.447859e+06 2.000000e+00 1.350000e+01 4.000000e+00
9.447859e+06 1.000000e+00 1.350000e+01 7.000000e+00
```

can I get a solution for this?
Thanks.

Comment: What have you tried? How did it fail?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
import numpy as np
a = np.array([[[1, 2,3, 4]], [[5, 6, 7, 8]]])

m,n,r = a.shape
out_arr = a.reshape(m*n,-1)
out_df = pd.DataFrame(out_arr,columns =['A','B','C','D'])
out_df
```

Result

```
    A   B   C   D
0   1   2   3   4
1   5   6   7   8
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use [`numpy.squeeze()`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.squeeze.html) to remove axes of length one from array.

```py
df = pd.DataFrame(np.squeeze(data), columns=['A', 'B', 'C', 'D'])
```

Comment: Best Readability and easy to initialize.

Answer (score 0):

You can specify which part of the array to use as data:

```
pd.DataFrame(data=a[:,0], index=range(0, len(a)), columns=['A', 'B', 'C', 'D'])
```

Answer (score 0):

This works (after removing the double brackets):

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
a = np.array([[9.447859e+06, 3.000000e+00, 1.350000e+01, 7.000000e+00],

   [9.447859e+06, 2.000000e+00, 1.350000e+01, 4.000000e+00],

   [9.447859e+06, 1.000000e+00, 1.350000e+01, 7.000000e+00]])

b = pd.DataFrame(data=a )
b
```